# Kotlin DateTimeformat returning wrong month

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime-format

Simple code, but something is wrong! I'm new to Kotlin, trying to take a date string and convert it into Date() format. When I convert back it gives wrong month. Example:

```
var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")
cal.set(2018, 1, 20)
val date: Date = cal.time
println(date)  //This prints: Tue Feb 20 23:25:59 EST 2018
```

Why am I getting Feb when month is set to 1 (January)?

Ultimately, I want to take a string in the format of "MM/dd/yyyy" and convert that to Date() format, but seem to be having trouble (need to support API 15), and using Calendar is my attempt to do this without the date formatters that need later APIs. Any ideas on a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Months for the `Calendar` class in Java are 0-indexed.

`cal.set(2018, 0, 20)`

is what you what.

However, this is why it's generally better to use the final int fields defined in the Calendar class, , rather than hardcoding the number. In this case, that's `JANUARY`. [See here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY).

So that would give:

`cal.set(2018, Calendar.JANUARY, 20)`

Answer (score 1):

The month is 0-based, so 0 is January, 1 is February, and so on

Answer (score 1):

> The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is
>   JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a
>   year.

So, to set January

```
var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")
cal.set(2018, 0, 20) // set Month field to Zero
val date: Date = cal.time
println(date)  //This prints: Sat Jan 20 23:25:59 EST 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar` for get months

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2018, Calendar.JANUARY, 20)//set date format
val date: Date = calendar.time
println(date)//print : 2018 Jan 20
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I getting Feb when month is set to 1 (January)?

You are getting **Feb** because at index `1 = FEB`

In `cal.set(2018, month index, 20)` method the second parameter having MONTH index parameter are indexed as below :

```
    0 = JAN

    1 = FEB

    2=MARCH

    3=APRIL

    4=MAY

    5=JUNE

    6=JULY

    7=AUG

    8=SEPT

    9=OCT

    10=NOV

    11=DEC
```

**Answer :** Use `Calendar.JANUARY` or `0` to solve your problem

```
var cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")
cal.set(2018, 0, 20)
val date: Date = cal.time
println(date)  //This prints: Tue Jan 20 23:25:59 EST 2018
```